# How can I move bunch of vertices to the origin of the world properly with Sverchok?

Tags: python, sverchok

Please see the image below. As you can see I am  finding the average value and moving all those verts by the same amount in the negative direction. It kind of works but what I want is to put that torus geometry (one drawn by Sverchok viewer) in to the center of the world based on a the calculated origin of the mesh.

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are couple of ways:
https://gist.github.com/d3fa712ed0a73e6db5ca08345402bd32
please, import gist layout - copy adress and press import from gist on panel

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the creative solutions, very helpful. What is wrong with my appoach btw? Is list math average doing something else than I think it should or a bug?

Answer (score 3):

List Math average isn't what I would use to find the average vector, we have an analyzer node for that. It expects inputs of Vertices, and employs an appropriate algorithm for that kind of input.

[image]

List Math expects primarily lists of numbers, (signified by the type of socket : green ) tweaking the `level` parameter will not result in returning the average of vectors. This is an understandably confusing situation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now that makes alot of sense.